# Why does this work in Java and String length

Tags: java, string, comparison

I just finished an issue in my homework, the purpose of this is to find the longest palindrome inside a string, so if you had a string "hellomomomkk" then it would return momom as the longest palindrome of this given string.

```
       for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        for(int j = i; j <= s.length(); j++) {
            if(isPalindrome(s.substring(i, j))) {
                if(s.substring(i, j).length() > longest.length()) {
                    longest = s.substring(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return longest;
```

isPalindrome is exactly what it says, returns true or false if the substring is a palindrome. My question is this. Why is it when I do

```
for(int j = i; j <= s.length(); j++)
```

My code works?? but if I do

```
for(int j = i; j < s.length(); j++)
```

My code is broken, and if the string were "Hello", j would end on **5** but the actual amount of characters is 4 starting from 0 count? so why isn't there an error in the <= code? And why does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
substring(i, j)
```

the j (the second arg) is considered to be at the left of the character at that index.

So if the string is

```
"A"
"A".substring(0, 1);

returns "A", as it ends before the character in slot 1 (which doesn't exist)
```

Comment: Oh! Now I get it :) Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

[`s.substring()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) excludes the end index.

Comment: wait now I'm confused lol, what do you mean it excludes the end index?

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you do a

```
s.substring(i, j)
```

The substring is from i till j excluding j so if

```
i = 0 
j = 5
```

Then the substring will contain 5 characters (as u said) but from 0-4 indexes (i:e 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

```
like if i = 2 and j = 6
```

the substring will contain (j - i = 6-2) 4 characters from index2-index5(i:e 2, 3,4, 5)